# C# .net, how to deploy class library dll when using 3rd party component references

Tags: asp.net, com, .net-assembly, class-library

This is my first post so here goes...

I have a c# .net class library I've build and been using in production for some time now. The project (using .net framework 3.5, output type Class Library, strongly named) didn't have any non-framework/standard references. It's set to be used as a COM component and we're using it against classic ASP websites. To deploy I'm setting the Build -> Configuration Manager to Release, building, copying the bin/release/PrintJob.dll file to our web servers. I then use regasm "c:\path info\PrintJob.dll" /tlb /codebase to register this on the server. At that point our classic ASP sites can successfully create an instance of the object and use it's functionality.

Today I've been tasked with implementing a new piece of functionality (encryption/decryption) using a 3rd party .net component. I'm used to working with ASP.NET applications more so that class libraries and COM components. So I update my existing project like I would a web project. I have the new dll on my computer, I first had to give it a strong name itself so my class library would accept it, I add the reference to the customCrypto.dll file in my application, reference the namespace in my class file(s), test it, build it, and it works fine locally.

I'm attempting to deploy it using the same method as previously. I go to the bin/release/ folder, copy the PrintJob.dll file to my web servers, register it the same, and when my sites attempt to use it now, it's throwing an exception that it can't find my customCrypto.dll file (the exceptions displays the full strong name assemply attributes).

So my question is am I doing this correctly? In a web project, the customCrypto.dll file is going to be moved along with my site automatically during the publish. So the dll automatically ends up with the project no problem. But with this class library, do I need to also copy the customCrypto.dll file to the other servers? When the build happened, how come my PrintJob.dll assembly didn't include this functionality internally. How do I get the COM component PrintJob.dll to be able to use the customCrypto.dll when deployed? Since the 3rd party customCrypto.dll component is a .net component, should I somehow be adding this to the machine and using it with my application another way?

I've spent the entire day trying to find references to this but all I can find are more direct issues like how to strongly name an assembly, add it as a reference, etc. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396161/using-a-3rd-party-com-dll-in-asp-net?rq=1